# the concept of the program is to create an abstract file and link to the implementation file but i get an error saying 'Student' does not a name type

Tags: c++

```
**Student.h**
```

** //this is is the code of the abstraction file**
 **// Student - a basic Student**
**the abstraction file will be linked to the implementation file to create a program that displays the name and id of student**

```
#ifndef _STUDENT_
#define _STUDENT_
namespace Schools
{
class Student
{
public:
Student(char* pszName, int nID);
virtual char* display()
protected:
```

** //students name**

```
char* pszName;
int nID;
};
}
#endif

**//Student.cpp**
**// this is the code of the implementation file**

**// Student - implementation of student**

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
namespace Schools
{
Student::Student(char* pszNameArg, int nIDArg): nID(nIDArg)
//create an array
pszName = new char[strlength(pszNameArg) + 1];
strcpy(pszName, pszNnameArg);
}
```

**// display function - shows a description of student
**

```
char* Student::display()

{


pReturn = new char[strlength(pszName) + 1];

strcpy(pReturn, pszName);



 return pReturn;
}
```

enter code here

Comment: where is the error? Is `char* Student::display()` also inside `namespace Schools` ?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_STUDENT_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores ar reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just remove the obvious typos and errors, your code works. And as @Pete Becker suggests, follow a proper name convention for the include guard, names starting with `_` are used by implementations. Use something like `HEADERNAME_H_` as followed commonly.

```
// Student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_
namespace Schools
{
class Student
{
public:
    Student(char* pszName, int nID);
    virtual char* display();
protected:
    char* pszName;
    int nID;
};
}
#endif
```

```
// Student.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Student.h"
namespace Schools 
{
Student::Student(char* pszNameArg, int nIDArg): nID(nIDArg)
{
    //create an array
    pszName = new char[strlen(pszNameArg) + 1];
    strcpy(pszName, pszNameArg);
}

char* Student::display()
{
    char* pReturn = new char[strlen(pszName) + 1];
    strcpy(pReturn, pszName);
    return pReturn;
}
}
```

But asking questions straightaway when you haven't even gone through your own code is no good.